# Expecting Cell Area instead of string in Java(Aspose)

Tags: java, java-6, aspose, aspose-cells

```
hyperlinks.add("A5", 1, 1, "C:\\book1.xls");
```

The following error i get in my eclipse.

> The method add(CellArea, String, String, String) in the type Hyperlinks is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, String)

```
Can anyone help me to resolve my problem ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the latest version: Aspose.Cells for Java v17.3.8 with the following code and it worked fine.

Please see the screenshot of the output excel file generated by this code.

[image]

**Java**

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);
ws.getHyperlinks().add("A5", 1, 1, "c:\\book1.xlsx");

wb.save(dirPath + "output.xlsx");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose